# xtrace cannot find its target program

Tags: bash, debugging, opensuse

opensuse leap 15.4 using icewm

Could someone kindly explain the following behavior of xtrace

```
~ $ xtrace xv *.tif*
executable `xv' not found
Try `xtrace --help' or `xtrace --usage' for more information.
~ $ whereis xv
xv: /usr/bin/xv /usr/share/man/man1/xv.1x.gz
~ $ echo $PATH
/home/qq/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
~ $ xtrace display *.tif*
executable `display' not found
Try `xtrace --help' or `xtrace --usage' for more information.
```

I got xtrace through the rpm package glibc-utils. I have removed and reinstalled that package and get same result.

Comment: AFIK, `xtrace` does not use `PATH` to find its target; you have to provide the path explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, yes, which makes sense as its really a debugger, though I don't use it for that purpose. I've only used it before on Lubuntu, where I never needed to supply the explicit path.

Comment: If you want to simulate the same behaviour, you could define a function `xtrace` which calculates the absolute path of the executable to be traced, and then invokes the external command `xtrace` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not I, but user1934428 answered it in his comment above, on opensuse at least one must supply the full path to the executable, though on Lubuntu that is not necessary.